# How to create and execute a Queue of Action<Task<bool>>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, queue, async-await

I'm looking to create an asynchronous callback mechanism where interested parties can register one or more callback methods.

I'd like to trigger and `await` completion of all the `Actions` in the queue and determine if any one of them has returned `true`.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to existing libraries or patterns to achieve this?

Comment: Wait for Queue to have item, dequeu, invoke wait for completeion (and return value) and repeat. What seems to be the the problem?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the question, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing out on any specialised classes for the job.

Comment: Specialised classes of what?

Comment: Something along the lines of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx , except for Actions.

Comment: Ok look, my answer almoast does that (i could implement a WaitAll method) but Actions don't have return values, are you sure you don't mean Func<bool> ?

Comment: Perhaps that's what I was after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to trigger and await completion of all the Actions in the queue and determine if any one of them has returned true.

If you want to invoke them all simultaneously and wait for them all to complete, then it can be done just like this:

```
IEnumerable<Func<Task<bool>>> queue = ...;
var results = await Task.WhenAll(queue.Select(x => x()));
return results.Any(x => x);
```

If you want to call them one at a time, then it can be done like this:

```
IEnumerable<Func<Task<bool>>> queue = ...;
foreach (var callback in queue)
{
  if (await callback())
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i was not exactly sure, where you intend to wait for completion of the async invocation I fiddled around a little and have a 2-way solution for you.

This solution provides 2 ways of getting informed about the completion of a method...

- ... via an `Event` that is triggered when any method completes (providing MethodInfo and Result in EventArgs)
- ... via a blocking getter in the `MethodInvokeState`

---

So to implement it you need the `MethodCompletedEventArgs`:

```
public class MethodCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private MethodInfo m_method;
    private Boolean m_result;
    public MethodCompletedEventArgs(MethodInfo mi, Boolean result)
    {
        m_method = mi;
        m_result = result;
    }
    public MethodInfo Method { get { return m_method; } }
    public Boolean Result { get { return m_result; } }
}
```

and the object that

- holds the target delegate
- returns the result (blocking)
- wraps around invoke (to provide the result)

Here the `MethodInvokeState`:

```
public class MethodInvokeState
{
    public MethodInvokeState(Func<bool> target)
    {
        m_target = target;
        m_mreCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        m_blnCompleted = false;
    }

    private Func<bool> m_target;
    private ManualResetEvent m_mreCompleted;
    private Boolean m_blnCompleted;
    private Boolean m_result;

    public Boolean WaitForCompletion()
    {
        if (!m_blnCompleted)
            m_mreCompleted.WaitOne();
        return m_result;
    }

    public Boolean Invoke()
    {
        m_result = m_target.Invoke();
        m_blnCompleted = true;
        m_mreCompleted.Set();
        return m_result;
    }
    public MethodInfo Method { get { return m_target.Method; } }

}
```

---

Finally you'll need the Scheduler, with following properties:

- It can register `MethodInvokeState` objects (enqueuing them)
- It can be initiated (so that it dequeues Methods and invokes them)
- It can be halted (aborting the invokation process)
- It provides a `MethodCompleted` event (using the above EventArgs)

Here the `MethodScheduler`:

```
public class MethodScheduler
{
    public MethodScheduler()
    {
        m_qAction = new Queue<MethodInvokeState>();
        m_mreNewAction = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        m_objQueueLock = new Object();
        m_blnClosing = false;
    }
    private Queue<MethodInvokeState> m_qAction;
    private ManualResetEvent m_mreNewAction;
    private Object m_objQueueLock;
    private Thread m_trdInvoker;
    private Boolean m_blnInvoking;
    private Boolean m_blnClosing;
    public delegate void MethodCompletedEventHandler(Object sender, MethodCompletedEventArgs e);
    public event MethodCompletedEventHandler MethodCompleted;        

    public void Init()
    {
        m_trdInvoker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(__invoker));
        m_blnInvoking = true;
        m_trdInvoker.Start();
    }

    private void __invoker()
    {
        while (m_blnInvoking)
        {
            int count = 0;
            lock (m_objQueueLock)
            {
                if((count = m_qAction.Count) == 0) 
                {
                    m_mreNewAction.Reset();                        
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) m_mreNewAction.WaitOne();
            if (!m_blnClosing)
            {
                MethodInvokeState p = m_qAction.Dequeue();

                bool result = p.Invoke();
                if (MethodCompleted != null)
                    MethodCompleted(p, new MethodCompletedEventArgs(p.Method, result));                                       
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        m_blnInvoking = false;
        m_blnClosing = true;
        m_mreNewAction.Set();
    }

    public void RegisterMethod(MethodInvokeState p) {
        if (!m_blnInvoking) throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot register a method if invoker is not initialized");
        Console.WriteLine(" * MethodScheduler: Registering Method: " +  p.Method.Name); 
        lock (m_objQueueLock)
        {
            m_qAction.Enqueue(p);
            m_mreNewAction.Set();
        }
    }      
}
```

---

Finally here an example how to use it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodScheduler ms = new MethodScheduler();
        ms.Init();
        ms.MethodCompleted += MethodCompletedHandler;

        MethodInvokeState mtA = new MethodInvokeState(new Func<bool>(SomeMethodA));
        MethodInvokeState mtB = new MethodInvokeState(new Func<bool>(SomeMethodB));

        ms.RegisterMethod(mtA);
        ms.RegisterMethod(mtB);

        Console.WriteLine(" * SENDER: Waiting for completion (SomeMethodA) ...");
        bool result = mtA.WaitForCompletion();
        Console.WriteLine(" * SENDER: SomeMethodA completed: " + result);

        Console.WriteLine(" * SENDER: Waiting for completion (SomeMethodB) ...");
        result = mtB.WaitForCompletion();
        Console.WriteLine(" * SENDER: SomeMethodB completed: " + result);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        ms.Stop();
    }

    public static void MethodCompletedHandler(Object sender, MethodCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * HANDLER: Method '{0}' completed with: {1} " , e.Method.Name, e.Result.ToString());
    }

    public static bool SomeMethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * SomeMethodA: will succeed in 5 seconds!");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return true;
    }
    public static bool SomeMethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * SomeMethodB: will fail in 3 seconds!");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think the code is quiete self explanatory. Please comment if any questions remain.